# How to get all subsites using ClientContext Object in SP 2010

Tags: client-object-model

I need to find all the subsites of particular sites and fill the drop down using ClientContext Object

Answer (score 2):

```
    function RetriveSites()
                    {
                    currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext(‘/collaboration/KeyWordsDemo’);   
    /* to get the current context use this instead -à.get_current();*/ 
     /*more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658863.aspx*/
                    currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
                    this.subsites = currentweb.get_webs();
                    currentcontext.load(this.subsites);
                    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(
                                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess),
                                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure));
                    }

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RetriveSites,’sp.js’);

}
```

Html of Dropdown which we are going to bind with sites

```
<select id=”teamsiteSelect” onchange=”navNow();”>
                <option value=”#”>Select Team Site…</option>
                <option value=”/collaboration/KeyWordsDemo”>Home</option>
</select>
```

code to bind dropdown

```
function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {
                var subs =”;
                var Siteenum = this.subsites.getEnumerator();
                while (Siteenum.moveNext())
                                {
                                var Site = Siteenum.get_current();
                                $(‘#teamsiteSelect’).append( $(‘<option></option>’).val(Site.get_serverRelativeUrl).html(Site.get_title));
                                }

                }

function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) {
                //alert(“error”);
}
```

for more detail follow:

http://slalomdotcom.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/creating-a-drop-down-navigation-menu-in-sharepoint-using-javascript/

Comment: mark it as answer if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Use [Web.Webs property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.webs%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to get a web sites *immediately beneath the Web site*:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var subWebs = ctx.Web.Webs;
    ctx.Load(subWebs);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Option 2**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve *all* web sites:

```
public static void LoadAllWebs(Web web,List<Web> allWebs)
{
    var ctx = web.Context;
    ctx.Load(web);
    ctx.Load(web.Webs);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    allWebs.Add(web);
    foreach (var subWeb in web.Webs)
    {
       LoadAllWebs(subWeb, allWebs);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    //load all webs in site collection
    var allWebs = new List<Web>();
    LoadAllWebs(ctx.Site.RootWeb,allWebs);

    //print 
    foreach (var web in allWebs)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    }
}
```